# Append to Firebase array without key

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array without keys. How can I append an element to the keyless array?

```
favorites:
- 0
  |
   -- name: "bs41"
- 1
  |
   -- name: "uie"
```

So my result would be:

```
favorites:
- 0
  |
   -- name: "bs41"
- 1
  |
   -- name: "uie"
- 2
  |
   -- name: "pts4"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best approach here would be a transaction.

But as usual: there are a lot of reasons why Firebase recommends against using arrays.

For example: can the same value be specified twice in `favorites`? Chances are that each user can only specify each favorite only once. So one of your next questions in that case is going to be: how can I prevent duplicate values in this Firebase array? And the answer to that one is again going to be: with a transaction.

Transactions hurt the performance and scalability of your application; and it also means that your app won't work when the user of offline. Whenever you need a transaction, it pays off to wonder if there is a data model that accomplishes the same use-case that doesn't require a transaction.

For storing favorites that could be as simple as putting the values into the keys of the collection:

```
favorites:
    "bs41": true
    "uie": true
    "pts4": true
```

Now you have an automatic guarantee that each favorite value can be present only once. Adding a new item is also incredibly simple: `ref.child("favorites").child("newfav").setValue(true)`.

The data model I just shared is how you model a set in Firebase. In my experience when you have an array/list and are checking if it contains a specific value before adding a new item, you often should be using a set instead.